# what is 1u server?

Tags: blade-server

what is actually meant by an 1u server? 
How can I check how many blade server does a chassis support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "U" is a *[Rack Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_unit)*, or 1.75 inches in height.  A 1U server would occupy a single unit's space within a rack.

You would need to update your question to detail which chassis you're asking about.  Different chassis can hold different numbers of blades, mezzanines, etc.

Comment: +1, Additionally: Blade Servers go in a Blade Chassis, not in a Rack. The Blade Chassis mounts to the Rack. Rack Servers also go directly into a Rack. And different Blade Servers tank up different amounts in a Blade Chassis, some are half-height or full-height, some are single width or double width. And some Blade Servers have additional units next to them to expand their functionality. So, you'll have to provide a lot more info if you want a precise answer.

Comment: or 4.5cm of course :)

Answer (score 1):

1u is a measurement of how much shelf space a server takes in a rack. 1u means one shelf space. Servers generally are 1u-4u but you can also get small 1/2u ones. Racks in a datacenter are commonly 48u.

How many blades fit in a chassis depends on the type of chassis. The specs from your manufacturer will show how many blade servers fit in their chassis. It's different for all manufacturers and models.

Answer (score 0):

I gleaned this from google:

1U Server= 1.75" of Vertical Rack Space
2U = 3.5" of Vertical Rack Space
4U = 7.00" of Vertical Rack Space

A full rack can contains 40 to 42U 1/4 Rack=10U (10 servers of 1U)
  Half rack =20 U (20 Servers of 1U)

Hope it helps

Comment: 48U is the most common "full" size in Enterprises, with 24 and 12 being half and quarter respectively. The smaller 40U units are more common in small/medium businesses where the rack cooling is attached on top of the rack.